# Better way to redirect after successful Community login

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-community

I have a custom login page for my Customer Community and I want to make sure that deep links into the community work correctly. For example, suppose I email a community user a link such as https://company.force.com/my_community/secure_content

...If they click the link, SF realises that they need to be logged in, so it sends them my custom login page, but keeps the window.location the same in the browser. With a naive login controller, a successful login will take them to the standard landing page, rather than the deep link. So, I've written it as follows:

VF:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.pathname.toUpperCase() !== '{!$Page.MyLoginPage}'.toUpperCase()) {
            $('input[id$=startPath]').val(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- more VF -->
<apex:inputHidden id="startPath" value="{!startPath}"/>
<!-- more VF -->
<apex:commandLink action="{!login}">
Sign in
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller (obviously, startPath is a property of the controller):

```
public PageReference login() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    if(startPath == null) {
        startPath = startUrl;
    }
    return Site.login(username, password, startPath);
}
```

It just feels wrong having to hit it with jquery, though. Is there a better way to figure out what the startUrl should be for situations like this? I guess you could say I should always use the startURL parameter, but I would rather not and I'm not certain that I have control of every possible way people could end up getting to the community anyway.